# What's the best type of tape to cover a pin on a connector?

Tags: rework

I have a pin (the flat kind--think a PCIe card) that I need to tape over to block the signal. What type of tapes work well for this? I tried electrician's tape, but it's a bit too thick and stretchy. I thought about masking tape, but I wasn't sure if it's electrically resistive enough for the job. The pin carries 5v.

Comment: Kapton tape? (polyamide?)

Comment: Some heat shrink...

Comment: @WesleyLee That looks perfect! Thank you.

Comment: @WesleyLee Kapton is polyimide not polyamide. Big difference in behavior in terms of stretching, puncturing and creepage.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested kapton tape is useful but sometimes can be a bit hard to work with for something so small. (for me anyway)
If its just the one finger pin you need to block and it is temporary you may find something like liquid electrical tape or conformal coating that you can lightly brush on easier to manage. If none of these are available to you, you might could even get by with a dab of fingernail polish.

If its permanent, why not just cut trace.